# Getting block by name in django template language

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm working on my website in django (1.4).
I have problem with getting block by its name (in order to edit it).

In every template that inherits from my basic template I have a string *blockname* assigned. I would like to put some text in a particular block (defined in extended template) which name is equal to content of variable *blockname*.

**EDIT:**

Example

*base.html*:

```
{% block b1 %}no changes{% endblock %}
{% block b2 %}no changes{% endblock %}
{% block b3 %}no changes{% endblock %}
```

*subpage.html*:

```
???
```

Displaying *subpage.html* with view like this:

```
def show_subpage(request):
    t = loader.get_template('subpage.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'blockname': 'b2'})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

should has result as below:

> no changes CHANGE no changes

How can I achieve that?

Comment: show us an example of what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: django does support nested blocks if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: And it also supports {% if %} whatever {% endif %}. Specific example, please, of what did/did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right then this is what you want...

```
def show_subpage(request):
    t = loader.get_template('subpage.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {'blockname': ' Change '})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

subpage.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block b2%}{{ blockname }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I can display a variable in template - it's nothing special. I try to put some text into one of the blocks of parent template, but in advance I don't know in which one. It is defined in variable *blockname* passed to template (value of this variable is a name of block that will be changed). F.e. if *blockname = b2*, block which name is *b2* should be changed, but if *blockname = b100*, block named *b100* must be change.

Comment: Ah. I understand what you're asking now... I don't think it's going to be possible to do this cleanly though.  The best I could suggest is a bunch of if statements in the template.  What's the use case for this?  Maybe we can figure out a better way to do what you're wanting.

Comment: Each template extends basic template, where there is a menu for whole website. In each template I have got a variable defining section of website where you currently are. I have hooks in this menu (as block tags) in order to have possibility to define class of each button/link. I can put string *"active"* to proper block in every template, but forgetting about changing it in the future will cause bugs. I would like a solution where you have to put some code merely into basic template - this code should use variable with current section to fill proper bookmark hook with string *"active"*.